# Running initializer method on a object called using jQuery getJSON

Tags: oop, jquery, coldfusion

I am having an issue when using the jQuery `$.getJSON` ajax call, though the issue would occur if I used any jQuery ajax method. Here is an example of the code.

```
$.getJSON('cfcs/contact.cfc?method=method', registrantData, function(data){ 
     // Data processing
});
```

Now the issue is, if I call my contact object in this manner, the initializer method for the object doesnt get called. So any of the dependencies I set up in the initializer are not available in the object methods. So if my contact object looks like below for example, calling the method function via Jquery ajax will fail.

```
..Contact.cfc
  function init(){
      injectedService  = new injectedService()
  }

 function method(){
     return injectedService.response();
 }
```

Is there anyway round this, as I dont want to have to refactor my objects specifically when they need to be called via ajax?

Thanks

Comment: What initializer method for what object? Are you trying to serialize an object which contains functions? JSON does not serialize functions. More context would be useful.

Comment: Matt, I think is example was pretty clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, it looks like you're going to have to create an proxy object to handle ajax calls if you need init() to fire off. So, ajax talks to proxy object. Proxy object creates cfc and passes arguments through and passes result back. That way, init will fire. This minimizes the change of all your objects to make this work.

Comment: Like this?                                       $.getJSON('cfcs/ajaxContactProxy.cfc?method=method', registrantData, function(data){ 
     // Data processing
});

Comment: Another benefit of the proxy (or façade) approach is that only the proxy has to have access="remote". All of your other business logic CFC methods can be access="public", and even live outside your Web root.

Comment: Thats a good point actually, wasnt too keen on making the function remote in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

A service framework like [Taffy](https://github.com/atuttle/Taffy) could help with this. The requests are funneled through Taffy's REST API, and Taffy instantiates your CFCs by requesting them from an object factory - I use [ColdSpring](http://www.coldspringframework.org/). ColdSpring will call the init() method on your service objects before invoking the service methods.

Comment: Not sure where the page went. Fixed the link to point to the actual GitHub master branch. I let the maintainer know about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, i think i prefer to use the proxy object to avoid adding more complexity to my overall code base, but this taffy framework looks like something i could use in several situations.